# Need help getting child nodes

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml, nodes

im reading my XML and looping through the child nodes when i move it to another server its stops working, any ideas on why it would stop..

here is the XML:

```
<masterxmlholder>   
    <userinfo login="user1">
    <rde-idea:lastlogin code="0">Wed Dec 31 17:00:00 MST 1969</rde-idea:lastlogin>
    </userinfo>

    <userinfo login="user2">
    <rde-idea:lastlogin code="4564568522258">Wed Dec 31 17:00:00 MST 1969</rde-idea:lastlogin>
    </userinfo>
</masterxmlholder>
```

and here is the loop i'm trying to get to the child with

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $user) {
    echo '<tr><td> Name :  </td><td>' . $user['login'] . $user->lastlogin '</td><td>';

}
echo '</table></center>';
```

Now I can get the name attribute to display from each of the child nodes, however I can NOT get any of the child's inner nodes to display

this is all trimmed down to give you the idea what im trying to do .. but its basically to see how im trying to access the child nodes and perhaps point out my flaw.

thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

The `lastlogin` info is actually a child of the `userinfo` node, so you will need to use the `children()` method again to retrieve the info. Note that in this example, I removed the XML namespace so that I could initialize `$xml`

```
$xmlstring = <<<XML
<masterxmlholder>   
    <userinfo login="user1">
    <lastlogin code="0">Wed Dec 31 17:00:00 MST 1969</lastlogin>
    </userinfo>

    <userinfo login="user2">
    <lastlogin code="4564568522258">Wed Dec 31 17:00:00 MST 1969</lastlogin>
    </userinfo>
</masterxmlholder>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);
echo '<center><table>';

foreach ($xml->children() as $user) {
    $name = $user['login'];
    foreach ($user->children() as $child ) {
       $lastlogin = $child;
    }
    echo '<tr><td> Name :  </td><td>' . $name . $lastlogin . '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table></center>';
```

I tested the code here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Side note, I would not use the `center` tag, as that is mixing presentation with content, which is frowned upon. Consider using [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) to style and position your table.

Comment: @jarrad im getting an undefined variable with your fix, do I need to declare the var in the foreach or before that ?

Comment: I don't have access to a php environment right now...I'll edit my answer with validated code later when I have access...

Comment: awesome!,, thanks for your help mate ! i look forward to your edits.

Comment: @jarrid ya but as i stated above i can NOT use the $user->lastlogin to return any results is there a spicific PHP setting that would block this child node? should i be looking for a setting in the PHP that will allow for it. it worked just fine in my environment but when i moved it to another location the server just borked out. im loading this with simpleXML i don't think that makes a difference.

Comment: speaking of borking, that last edit was all messed up. should be right now...sorry about that.